# How can I make a copy text button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a different right click context menu and want to include a 'Copy text' button, But I dont know what type of code to use. I have tried `CopyText(this.form.txtSelect);` but have not put it in properly/It isnt compatible, and also how would I would I remove the bullets, I tried changing it to something like `<a>` but it doesnt use the css style
Here is my current script:
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Samdenty99/ctsgw1tq/)

HTML:

```
TEST Text
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action = "first">Copy Text</li>
  <li data-action = "second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function CopyText(el){
    var selectedText = "";
    if(window.getSelection){
        selectedText = window.getSelection();
    }else if (document.getSelection){
        selectedText = document.getSelection();
    }else if (document.selection){
        selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    if(selectedText != ""){
        selectedText = selectedText.toString();
        el.focus();
        el.value = selectedText;
        }else {
        alert("Select a text in the page and then press this button!");
    }
}
// Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {

    // Avoid the real one
    event.preventDefault();

    // Show contextmenu
    $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).

    // In the right position (the mouse)
    css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
});


// If the document is clicked somewhere
$(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {

    // If the clicked element is not the menu
    if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {

        // Hide it
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
    }
});


// If the menu element is clicked
$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){

    // This is the triggered action name
    switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {

        // A case for each action. Your actions here
        case "first": CopyText(this.form.txtSelect); break;
        case "second": alert("second"); break;
        case "third": alert("third"); break;
    }

    // Hide it AFTER the action was triggered
    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
  });
```

CSS:

```
.custom-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #FAFCFD;
    color: #6E6E6E;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.custom-menu li {
    padding: 8px 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #49C1FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: your code tries to copy the selected text to a form field called txtSelect, but that form field does not exist

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Is there any other code that can copy the highlighted text, I searched online and could not find any results for this

Comment: @XLR8 Just make an invisible form field to put your text in using JavaScript